# KO Computed recalculating but not updating UI

Tags: knockout.js

I'm relatively new to knockout and hitting some issues with observables. This is a paired down version of some knockout I'm using:

```
var model;
function viewModel(data) {
    var self = this;       
    self.favesData = ko.observableArray(data.User.Favorites);       
    self.splitRows = ko.computed(function () {
        var i = 0;
        var faveRows = [];
        var size = 2;
        while (i < self.favesData().length) {
            faveRows.push(self.favesData().slice(i, i += size));
        }
        return faveRows;
    });

    self.refresh = (function (data) {
        self.favesData(data.User.Favorites);
    });
}

function onComplete(result) {
    if (!model) {
        model = new viewModel(result);
        ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(result));
    } else {
        model.refresh(result);
    }
}

<table class="table-main link" data-bind="foreach: splitRows">
    <tr data-bind="foreach: $data">
        <td>
            <div class="link">
                <a href="#" data-bind="text: $data.Name">
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

I use an ajax GET, which calls onComplete. The data comes in just fine and everything binds great on the initial load. I then call the same ajax function with new input, which starts to work correctly - the data is returned and different, the refresh updates favesData, and splitRows recalculates, but the UI display never changes. 
Shouldn't splitRows update the binding when it recalculates? 
I'm pretty confused about how passing new data to favesData can update the computed observable that watches it, but the computed observable doesn't update the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your onComplete method you are not binding the Markup to the model, but to a new instance of the viewModel it should be like below.

```
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

the refresh is being called on a model that is not used by the UI

Answer (score 0):

Try [clearing the array and pushing the new items in](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html), something like;

```
 self.favesData.removeAll();
 data.User.Favorites.each(function(fav) { self.favesData.push(fav); });
```

to see if that sorts it out. I tend to use the official [knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), which does a really good job of 'knockouting-up' models from the server, and refreshing them.

So typically you'd end up refreshing by doing something like this inside your viewmodel

```
self.refresh = function(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
}
```

to re-bind the whole model.

Comment: I don't understand why people push items from an array into an observable array. Just put the array in there. Or if you need it to be a separate copy of the array, use `slice`.

Comment: @RoyJ - that's what the OP seems to be doing in their refresh method, but it's not working. clearing and re-setting might give a clue about what's going wrong.